# Regex for matching string to list of queries

Tags: python, regex

I have a query result string as an input and list of sql queries.

I want to check that result string can be output of which of the sql queries.

For example :

result string

```
val = 15.1a
```

List of queries:

```
  ["select * from table where val like "15%",
     "select * from table where val in ("15.1a", "15.1b"),
     "select * from table where val = "15.1",
     "select * from table where val != "15",
     "select * from table where val = "18",
    ]
```

So here you can see that, if i run 0,1,3 index queries it will give the result string.

Is there any way i can do that in python.
I dont want to use sql engine for that, rather than I am looking for some regex which can does that work.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Regex is probably not the right tool for this job

Comment: I just want to get list of queries which would give me result string without using sql.

Comment: @DeepSpace any other python tool which can help

Comment: Do you have only one condition on val or your list of query is more complicated than this?

Comment: Do you have the data in any other format? If you want to use python you have to load the data in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question:

```py
import re

query_list = [
    "select * from table where val like '15.1%'",
    "select * from table where val in ('15.1a', '15.1b')",
    "select * from table where val = '15.1'",
    "select * from table where val != '15'",
    "select * from table where val = '18'",
]

# pattern to capture only the value used in comparing
#  val like '%some%value'  will return   str %some%value without quotes
operations = {
    'like': r".*?(?:val\slike\s+')(.*)(?:'.*)",
    'in': r".*?(?:val\s+in\s+\()(.*)(?:\).*)",
    '=': r".*?(?:val\s+=\s+')(.*)(?:'.*)",
    '!=': r".*?(?:val\s+\!=\s+')(.*)(?:'.*)",
}

valid_query = []
val = '15.1a'

for query in query_list:
    for op, pattern in operations.items():
        m = re.match(pattern, query)
        if m:
            comparing_value = m.groups(0)[0]
            if op == 'like':
                # here we use regex with non greedy operator
                pcomparing_value = r'{}'.format(comparing_value.replace('%', '.*?'))
                if re.match(pcomparing_value, val):
                    valid_query.append(query)

            # compare val without quotes must be equal
            elif op == '=' and val == comparing_value:
                valid_query.append(query)

            # compare val without quotes must not be equal
            elif op == '!=' and val != comparing_value:
                valid_query.append(query)

            # for in operator compare val with quotes too
            elif op == 'in' and "'{}'".format(val) in comparing_value:
                valid_query.append(query)


print(valid_query)
```

Output for `val = '15.1a'`:

```
["select * from table where val like '15.1%'", "select * from table where val in ('15.1a', '15.1b')", "select * from table where val != '15'"]
```

Output for `val = '15'`  is `[]`

Output for `val = '18'`  is :

```
 ["select * from table where val != '15'", "select * from table where val = '18'"]
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. this is what I wanted to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

val = r'^.*15.1.*,'
text = ' "select * from table where val in ("15.1a", "15.1b"),  select * from table where val = "15.1",'

print (re.findall(val, text))
```

**OUT**

```
[' "select * from table where val in ("15.1a", "15.1b"),  select * from table where val = "15.1",']
```

Comment: Here we are searching for 15.1a and expected output is values indexed at 0,1,3